Openpyxl-created Data Validation Dropdowns only show after manually disabling and then re-enabling "In Cell Dropdown"
I am trying to write Data Validation to a large number of cells using Openpyxl. I am able to successfully write them, and the dropdown arrows show when I open the document.
However, clicking the dropdown error does nothing. This can be fixed by going to Data > Data Validation and unchecking "In-cell Dropdown", closing out of the window, then re-opening and re-enabling "In-cell dropdown".
How can I fix this issue, or at least work around it?
Code:
#NOTE: This method assumes rows_per_tactic is consistent for each tactic and that there is 5 rows before the first tactic
def write_technique_data_validation(wb, sheet_name, rows_per_tactic, data):
    ws = wb[sheet_name]
    tactics = data.get_tactics()
    #Iterate through the second column. Total number of roles
    for tactic in tactics:
        row_of_current_tactic = tactics.index(tactic) * (rows_per_tactic + 1) + 6
        data_validation_obj = DataValidation(
            type = 'list',
            formula1 = f"=XLOOKUP($A${row_of_current_tactic},'Tactics to Techniques'!$A$1:$A$14,'Tactics to Techniques'!$B$1:$Q$15)",
            allow_blank = True,
            showDropDown = False
            )
        # Find the "count" of the current tactic, multiply that by rows per tactic (plus one for the tactic name row itself)
        # add 7 to account for rows used for information at top of sheet
        start_of_tactic_range = tactics.index(tactic) * (rows_per_tactic + 1) + 7

        #same here but add the rows_per_tactic and decrease the offset by one to avoid double-counting the name row
        end_of_tactic_range = tactics.index(tactic) * (rows_per_tactic + 1) + 6 + rows_per_tactic
        data_validation_obj.add(f'B{start_of_tactic_range}:B{end_of_tactic_range}')
        
        ws.add_data_validation(data_validation_obj)

While I could do this process for each data validation in the sheet, it's a very large sheet and this is part of a process I am trying to automate.
I have tried setting showDropdown in init to both False and True, as well as removing it entirely.

We don't know what tactics = data.get_tactics() provides and therefore the make up of your Datavalidation.
